# error message in submitting on a form using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I wan to create a form with error message like this :

[image: My Form]

```
<div class="box-content">   
<?php
$properties = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'form1');
echo form_open("control_perbaikan/userRequest", $properties);
?>

<fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Kind Of Complaint :</label>
        <div class="controls" id="chekboxes">
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > Login </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Printer" value="Printer"> Printer </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Monitor" value="Monitor"> Monitor</label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Computer" value="Computer"> Computer</label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Network" value="Network"> Network</label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Other" value="Lain-lain" > Other</label> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group hidden-phone">
        <label class="control-label" for="Keluhan" >Description: </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="cleditor" name="keluhan" id="keluhan" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit"  >Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I have tried some like this : [JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8hWg/35/) . 
But I still confused how to do it with my form. How to put the error like in picture ..

This is my code : [My JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Fadly_Dzil_Massere/a59n4dh5/)
Thanks ...

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be adding the resources that are needed for `jquery Validation` plugin to work correctly.Hope the following could help u mate. :)

```
$.validator.addMethod("inline", function () {
     return $("#form1").find(".inline:checked").length > 0;
 }, 'Please select at least one .');

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("input[name=request]").change(function () {
         var me = $(this);

         otherInputs.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
         otherInputs.attr("value", "");

     });

     $("#form1").validate({
         errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
             if ($(element).hasClass("one_required")) {
                 error.insertAfter($(element).closest("table"));
             } else {
                 error.insertAfter(element);
             }
         },
         rules: {
             'request[]': {
                 required: true
             },
                 'keluhan': {
                 required: true
             }
         },
         submitHandler: function (form) {
             $("#errorDiv").html("");
             form.submit();
         }

     });
 });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u5fz7yao/)

**FYI**

Jquery validate Documentation [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)